# How to use wget to download HTTP error pages?

Tags: wget

`wget` normally stops when it gets a HTTP error, e.g. 404 or so. Is there an option to make `wget` to download the page content regardless of the HTTP code?

Comment: You can use `curl` instead.

Answer (score 78):

[Parameter: `--content-on-error`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-Content-On-Error), available from wget 1.14:

> If this is set to on, wget will not skip the content when the server responds with a http status code that indicates error.

Comment: @lilydjwg  interestingly the option --content-on-error is not on here http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Wgetrc-Commands    - but is on man wget ftp://ftp.connect.org.uk/hpux/Gnu/wget-1.14/wget-1.14.man.html

Comment: @barlop that's because the first link you linked is for wget 1.13.4, and the latter is for wget 1.14. `--content-on-error` was [added at 1.14](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7323).

Comment: @lilydjwg well, if the online manual is going to be a man page, one would think they should update it to the latest man page.

Comment: The linked manual is now the 1.15 one, which includes the mentioned option.

Comment: `--content-on-error` seems not to be working in case of `401` response. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393616/how-to-get-http-server-response-in-case-of-401-using-wget).